# Как передать заголовок формы в переменную php?

Tags: php, формы

Есть самописный лендинг. На сайте много форм. Все они используют один обработчик. Появилась задача уникализировать письма, которые приходят с этих форм, что бы понимать с какого товара поступила заявка. 
Первое, что приходит в голову это передавать в тело письма заголовок формы ( они разные). 
Проблема в том, что я не владею php  и гугл не сильно помог в этом деле :(. Прошу помощи у вас.

Comment: Переформулируйте вопрос, добавьте пример кода. В настоящий момент не понятно, что и как у вас написано

Answer (score 2, accepted):

обычно в форму вставляют скрытый `<input type="hidden" name="mail_tempate" value="dress"/>`
где value = название шаблона письма

Затем составляют сборщик шаблонов писем  - у писем могут быть одинаковые элементы
а в PHP коде уже ставят проверку на значение mail_tempate.

```
 //по простому - если в теле формы прописан <form method="post" ></form>
if($_POST['mail_tempate'] == 'dress'){
  //применить форму письма для одежды
}
```

Comment: Да, интересно. Это решит проблему. 
А возможно передавать в этот скрытый инпут, например заголовок h3 поп-апа, где находится форма?))

Comment: конечно можно все - вы можете это реализовать как на php - найдя переменную которая вставляется в этот h3 либо на javascript путем работы с DOM элементами